# Mongoose .find is giving me dates in the wrong format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose, momentjs

so on MongoDB I have a Date object stored as this:

`"$date": "2015-08-27T13:50:49.000Z"`

So the date on MongoDB is correct. Then, I am using a Mongoose `.find()` to get the 'newest' message in that database like this:

```
Message.find({}).sort({ "created_at" : -1 })
  .limit(1)
  .exec(function(error, result) {
    if(error) callback(error);
    var date = moment(result.created_at);
    console.log(date);
    console.log(result);
    callback(null, result);
});
```

So when I log `result` to the console, which is the Message itself, it shows me the time as this:

`created_at: Thu Aug 27 2015 21:50:49 GMT+0800 (CST)`

The time is correct, but I don't want to receive the date as GMT when it is clearly stored on MongoDB as UTC. In this specific example, `moment(result.created_at)` prints the date to console like this:

```
{ [Number: 1440685886247]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _isUTC: false,
  _locale: 
   { _ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
     ordinal: [Function],
     _abbr: 'en',
     _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _d: Thu Aug 27 2015 22:31:26 GMT+0800 (CST) }
```

Somehow this is actually printing the current time according to my laptop. I have no idea why it is doing this when `date` is declared as `moment()` using the date from MongoDB.

So does anyone know how I can successfully use the date from my database? When printing the Message to console I get it printed in GMT and when using moment I seem to be printing my laptop's time.

Thanks!

**Update:**

So far I have tried taking `result.created_at` from the database and outputting it to console using the following methods:

```
var date = Date(result.created_at) // Prints current time on laptop
var date = new Date(result.created_at) // Prints undefined
var date = result.created_at // Prints undefined
var date = moment(result.created_at) // Prints moment object with the time as computer's time
```

I am a bit stuck. I want to use this date object for another function but can only get it to hold the computer's time.

Comment: Well in a `console.log()` the `Date` objects just stringify. And the default `.toString()` method for `Date` produces the local time string you are seeing. The "actual" date Objects are quite normally the UTC values you expect. So your `moment` calls should expect a JavaScript `Date` object and not a "string" as you seem to be doing.

Comment: Interesting, how do you propose that I go about taking the `Date` from the database, and getting its `String` equivalent so that I can use that? Essentially I need it as a String so that I can make an API request using it. When logging `moment(result.created_at)` it is also showing the local time though? Even though it is the `Date` object passed directly from the `.find()`. Thanks for your replies to my questions over the past couple of days by the way, I'm definitely not the most knowledgable person on Mongoose/MongoDB, I'm more of a design/frontend guy!

Comment: You need to learn a bit more here. I have given you help a few times but keep learning. You are doing things the wrong way. Learn the right way. Which is "do not send striings". Use "timestamps" to external API's, which all know how to handle the data in any language.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I have done as you said and have tried saving `created_at` as `Date` or `new Date(created_at)` or as `moment(created_at)` and when printing them to console they all still give me the computer's time, and when I use these timestamps in the API they also do the same. In fact, `new Date(created_at)` actually returns `undefined` to console as well.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, if I do something like `var date = result.created_at; console.log(date.toUTCString())` then I get `Cannot read property 'toUTCString' of undefined`. And the same if I just try logging `result.created_at.toUTCString()`

Comment: @JohnnyHK It is displaying the date correctly on MongoDB when I inspect the database, and it is defined prior to inserting into the database as `date = new Date(created_at)` which is a String from the API as I showed in my OP. Mongoose also defines in the Schema that it is of type `Date`. I'm not sure where it would be saved as undefined because it's definitely in MongoDB as a date, and when I output the `result` from the database it shows me the correct date in the console as shown in the OP. Where do you think it would be `undefined`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I also just checked and the `new Date()` which is defined and used to insert the data into the database logs fine to console showing the correct date and not `undefined`.

Comment: With `find`, the `result` parameter is an array, even though you've limited the results to 1 doc.  So it would be `result[0].created_at.toUTCString()`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Oh man, thanks. If you want to write that as an answer feel free. My original method I was trying was actually correct but the "date" I was trying to use was wrong. Rather stupid for not seeing the `[ ]` around the result.

Comment: @germainelol No worries, these ones where there are two completely separate issues at play can make it tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're having here is that with `find`, the `result` parameter of the callback is an array, even though you've limited the results to 1 doc.

So to access the one doc's `created_at` property it would be:

```
result[0].created_at
```

Then, to get a string version of its contained date and time in UTC, call [`toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) on it:

```
result[0].created_at.toUTCString()
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why exactly it is that I could use `result.created_at` when playing around with it in console? I could actually use it as a `Date` object and it would still output a "date" to console. I guess what it was actually doing was creating an empty `new Date`, which in fact just prints the local time because the variable wasn't valid or was `undefined`. My assumption was that I was doing something wrong because it was showing a date, just the wrong date.